# How to fix Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported in a 'Google My Maps' embed

Tags: google-maps

How to fix the console error:

> Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported

I have found an answer to this question for Google Maps here in stack overflow, but I am using 'Google My Maps' and I'm embedding on my website iframes like this one:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1Jv-Y-c2bvAGOxKGHJxDq5MeF6cGf5gS3&ehbc=2E312F" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

As you can see, it is not necessary a Google API since it is Google My Maps.

I saw in the other topic that the short answer is to specify a callback value like these two:
&callback=Function.prototype
&callback=initMap

Can someone help me on showing me where I need to place these callbacks on an iframe like the one above? I own a travel agency website so I have like 90 pages with a map each, and I am afraid this is hurting my Google search.

I'm a no coder, so if someone could help me with a simple solution, I would appreciate it very much.

I tried to add both of these callbacks:
&callback=Function.prototype
&callback=initMap

To the iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1Jv-Y-c2bvAGOxKGHJxDq5MeF6cGf5gS3&ehbc=2E312F&callback=Function.prototype" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

But it didn't work.
Thank you in advance for your help!